# Format date field in twig

Tags: 8, theming, datetime

Date field having multiple values. Need to format the output.

```
{% for item in items %}
<div{{ attributes }}>{{ item.content|date(format="F j, Y") }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

`item.content` showing the date as updated. But not able to format the result. Got the below error,

> TypeError: DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string,
>   array given in...

Please suggest on this issue.

Comment: Use the field formatter date options in the admin configuration of this content type.

Answer (score 5):

In Twig, drill down to the timestamp value:

**node.html.twig**:

```
{{ content.field_name['#items'].value | date('F d, Y') }}
```

For a loop, do:

```
{% for items in content.field_name['#items'] %}
  {{ items.value | date('F d, Y') }}
{% endfor %}
```

**field.html.twig**:

```
{% for item in items %}
  {{ item.content["#markup"] | date('F d, Y') }}
{% endfor %}
```

Note: *Set field format display option to `plain` or `custom` if using the field template. This field option can break your site just by someone changing the format option for the field, so use caution.*

Comment: Thanks. I'm using that code in twig field template : `field--node--field-date--calendar-event.html.twig` (`field--node--[field-name]--[content-type].html.twig`). So, I tried `content.field_date` in the loop instead of `content.field_date_field`. But didn't get any result. Please advise.

Comment: Added a field template option to the answer.

Comment: The date field does have a custom format option as well that allows custom formatting of the field value.

Comment: Thanks @Prestosaurus I just did it using **preprocess** function based on content type.